# In SQL how to apply Ntile for the below case

Tags: sql, sql-server

INPUT

```
BOX COLOR
100 ABC
100 ABC
100 ABC
200 XYZ
200 XYZ
300 CCC
300 CCC
300 CCC
300 CCC
400 ANC
400 ANC
```

Expected OUTPUT

```
OUTPUT      

ID  BOX COLOR
1   100 ABC
1   100 ABC
1   100 ABC
2   300 CCC
2   300 CCC
2   300 CCC
2   300 CCC
3   200 XYZ
3   200 XYZ
4   400 ANC
4   400 ANC
```

Comment: Depends on the DB engine you use.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Also, do you really need an `ntile`? Seems your id is just `box/100`.

Comment: Did you try `NTILE` and it didn't return "correct" numbers, i.e. rows with the same `BOX` in the same quantile? Can you add some more data & expected result?

Comment: This makes no sense. How is 300 before 200 or ANC after XYZ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use DENSE_RANK function to get the result

```
 SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY BOX), BOX, COLOR
 FROM YourTable
```

Comment: The same i tried and it's works for me thanks but my requirement is different.I have posted in expected result again

Comment: I'm not sure we can use using NTILE, based on you expected output, we need distribute 11 rows across 4 groups, then first 3 groups (9 rows), each group will have 1, 2, 3 respectively and the last group with 2 rows will have 4. `SELECT NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY BOX) FROM YourTable`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want `NTILE` which puts the same value in the same quantile.

The logic for caluculating `NTILE` is based on some integer calculation using `ROW_NUMBER` similar to (but not exactly the same):

```
4 * (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COLOR?) - 1) / COUNT(*) OVER ()
```

When you switch to `RANK` instead you probably get what you want:

```
4 * (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COLOR?) - 1) / COUNT(*) OVER ()
```